# Gatekeeper Configuration Data 14.0

Tags: macos, software-update, gatekeeper

I recently received Gatekeeper Configuration Data 14.0 installed automatically without any notice on my MBP, it's not shown on the normal "Software Update" list. But can be found via Apple > About This Mac > More Info > System Report > Installations. (OS X 10.8.5)

Did anyone else receive that too? and what is it for? I checked few other Macs none of them have it.

UPDATE: this is a quicker way to check it - click the Apple icon on the top menu, press and hold the alt/option key, it turns "About this Mac" to "System Information" then click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about Gatekeeper here:

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5290
https://www.apple.com/osx/what-is/security.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gatekeeper_(OS_X)

I have not seen v14.0 myself,

Comment: Did you receive any other versions of it - Gatekeeper Configuration Data? Why I got it on one Mac not the others? Is there anything I should worry about?

Comment: Yes, I have Version 12.0 on all my machines, but all my machines are on 10.9.4 or 10.10, I don't have a 10.8 machine. It is **not** something you should worry about.

Comment: Since you mention you only get v12.0 on all your Macs, it seems it doesn't get any further updates once it installed the first one. Anyway I will update this when I have more information about it.